# How to Integrate tinymce editor in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs,working with nextjs and i am trying to integrate Editor
in my page but i am getting following error

```
"TypeError: editor1 is null"
```

How can i fix this ? I tried with following code, Where i am wrong ?

```
const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let editor: any = null;
  const content = editor.getContent();

  const data = {
    first: e.target.name.value,
    last: e.target.cat_name.value,
    content: content, // add the content to the data object
  }
};

<Editor
  onInit={(evt, ed) => editor = ed} // set the editor reference
  initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
  init={{
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
    'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
    'removeformat | help',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
  }}
/>
```